# how to insert a (BOOL *) into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to save a boolean database value into a map as follows -

```
[recentTags setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[aMessage isSet]] forKey:[aMessage tagName]];
```

It gives me an error saying "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending BOOL *  aka signed char* to 'BOOL' aka signed char"

How would I insert a BOOL* into the dictionary?

Comment: Why does `-isSet` return `BOOL *` instead of `BOOL`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Wrap the BOOL in an [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSNumber *boolNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

To get it out:

```
BOOL b = [boolNumber boolValue];
```

You can wrap other non-object types (such as a pointer or a struct) in an [NSValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

---

EDIT: Assuming you really mean a BOOL* (pointer):

```
NSValue *boolValue = [NSValue value:pointerToBool withObjCType:@encode(BOOL*)];
BOOL *b = [boolValue pointerValue];
```

Comment: As you can see in my question I am already doing that but it's not working for me. That is when I get the error that I have mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure `[aMessage isSet]` is returning a BOOL and not a BOOL*?  If it returns the latter, you need to use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:*[aMessage isSet]]` (although you should first check that it is not NULL).

Comment: Starting with Clang v3.1, we can use literals: `NSNumber *yesNumber = @YES;` and `NSNumber *noNumber = @NO;`, equivalent to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` etc

Answer (score 0):

Your `isSet` method would need to have the following signature:  `- (BOOL)isSet;`

Assuming that is the case, there shouldn't be any problem using NSNumber as mentioned by titaniumdecoy.

Your last sentence intrigues me, `BOOL *`.  Surely you mean `BOOL`, if you absolutely *need* a boolean reference, then I would suggest you store the initial/actual BOOL in a NSNumber and store the references that object wherever you'd need it (i.e. your NSMutableDictionary).